# Example of built-in Angular comment directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In Angular JS there are four ways to express directives:

- element names (`<my-dir></my-dir>`)
- attributes (`<span my-dir="exp"></span>`)
- class names (`<span class="my-dir: exp;"></span>`
- comments (`<!-- directive: my-dir exp -->`)

Last type is seldom used and mostly seen in presentations about creating custom directives. I'm preparing a training about Angular and I want to show all types of directives without introducing custom directive code. Surprisingly I can't find any built-in comment directive. Is there any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[In the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) there is a comment (no pun intended) about the comment option for directives that may give you some direction:

> Best Practice: Comment directives were commonly used in places where
>   the DOM API limits the ability to create directives that spanned
>   multiple elements (e.g. inside  elements). AngularJS 1.2
>   introduces ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end as a better solution to
>   this problem. Developers are encouraged to use this over custom
>   comment directives when possible

So it seems that this type of directive is discouraged and digging into the `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` may provide insight into how they got around them. While it might be educational to show each type of directive in action, if the practice is discouraged this may be the best thing you can do is provide this information in your presentation rather than show off discouraged code practices.

Also, [doing a search in their repo](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=restrict%20M&type=Code) for anything with `restrict` set to 'M' I was unable to find anything. That seems to help confirm that the team values their own advice and avoids this use themselves.

Comment: @Landeeyo No problem. Good luck on your training!